# Snowpipe Issue - Azure data lake storage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We're running into an issue where snowpipe is probably starting to ingest the file even before it gets fully written in azure data lake storage.

It then throws an error - Error parsing the parquet file: Invalid: Parquet file size is 0 bytes.

Here are some stats that show that file was fully written at 13:59:56 and snowflake was notified at 13:59:47.

PIPE_RECEIVED_TIME - 2021-08-06 13:59:47.613 -0700

LAST_LOAD_TIME - 2021-08-06 14:00:05.859 -0700

ADLS file last modified time - 13:59:56

Has anyone run into this issue or have any pointers for troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen something similar once. I was trying to funnel Azure Logs into a storage account and have them picked up. However, the built in process that wrote the logs would create a file, gradually append updates to it with new logs, and then every hour or so, cut over to a new file for more logs.

the Snowpipe would pick up the file with one log (or none) and from there, the azure queue would no longer send another event for that file so Snowflake would never query it again to process it.

So I'm wondering if your process is creating the file and then updating it. Rather than creating it with the output already fully ready to write.

If this is the issue, and you don't have control of how the file is created. you could try use a task that runs COPY INTO on a schedule (rather than a snowpipe) so that you can restrict the list of files getting copied to just files that have finished writing fully.

Comment: We intent to run pipeline NRT so enabling auto ingest is a requirement. With schedule based approach, we're looking at unnecessary complexities assuming auto ingest works fine.

Comment: Then I would start with investigating how your file is getting created to see if this is the same issue.